# class_id support for categorical deep learning problems in R (keras / tensorflow) using metric_recall_at_precision or metric_precision_at_recall

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, model, metrics

Using R 3.6.3, keras 2.9.0 and tensorflow 2.9.0 on a Windows 10 machine with GPU support (reticulate points to python 3.6.10)
I can't compile a model (3 categorical classes) using the optional `class_id` argument for metrics `metric_recall_at_precision` and `metric_precision_at_recall`.  The following error is produced:

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'class_id'

The keras documentation for these metrics clearly states that "class_id" is an optional argument...
The model compiles correctly using  `metric_sparse_categorical_accuracy` or if I convert the model to binary classification (sigmoid output) and use `metric_recall_at_precision` or `metric_precision_at_recall`

Here is the code for a (simplified) model generating the error:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
     layer_conv_1d(filters = 64, kernel_size = 11, strides = 5, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(446,3)) %>% 
     layer_max_pooling_1d(pool_size = 5) 

model %>% 
    layer_dropout(rate = 0.1) %>%
    layer_flatten() %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu") %>%
    layer_dense(units = 3, activation = "softmax")  

model %>% compile(
    optimizer = "adam",
    loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",   
    metrics =  metric_recall_at_precision(precision=precision, class_id=0))
```

Any idea how to get this model compiled using a class_id argument?

Comment: What is your `precision` value?

Comment: What tensorflow version are you using? `tensorflow::tf_config()`

Comment: Precision = 0.6 (but anything from 0 to 1 can do)

Comment: Tensorflow version: TensorFlow v2.2.0

Comment: I used `Tensorflow version 2.9.1` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the Tensorflow version in my python virtual environment solved the problem!  I upgraded to `Tensorflow v2.6.0` and I can now compile my model!

Thanks to **t-kalinowski** and **Quinten** for the pointers!